# Varnish error "Uncached req.body can only be consumed once" by extracting response header from subrequest and add it to the original request

Tags: api, varnish, varnish-vcl, http-caching

I have an api with jwt authentication (bearer token). The jwt is sent on every api request. For validating the jwt I have a specific route in my backend (`GET /_jwt_user_sub`). A request to this route with a valid jwt returns a `X-User` response header with code `200` and `Content-Type: application/vnd.user-sub`. I configured Varnish to make on every api call (`GET` and `POST`) a sub request to this route, extract the `X-User` header from the response and add it to the originally api request. This jwt user id response should be cached by varnish. For api requests with `GET` method this works fine but not for api calls with `POST` method because Varnish by default do all backend requests with `GET`. So I override this behaviour in the `vcl_backend_fetch` sub routine (see following vcl configuration).

With my vcl configuration I get a `Error 503 Backend fetch failed`. By debugging with `varnishlog` I see that a vcl error is thrown: `VCL_Error  Uncached req.body can only be consumed once.`. I am not sure how to rewrite the configuration correctly, as the error says at one point the configuration tries to consume a request body twice without caching it. Varnish should only cache `GET` api calls, no `POST` calls.

This is my vcl configuration:

```
vcl 4.1;
import std;
import xkey;

backend app {
    .host = "nginx";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = app;

    // Retrieve user id and add it to the forwarded request.
    call jwt_user_sub;

    // Don't cache requests other than GET and HEAD.
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hit {
   if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
       return (deliver);
   }

   if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
       if (!std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
           return (deliver);
       } else if (req.http.cookie) {
           return (miss);
       }

       return (deliver);
   }

   return (miss);
}

// Called when the requested object has been retrieved from the backend
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.http.accept ~ "application/vnd.user-sub"
        && beresp.status >= 500
    ) {
        return (abandon);
    }
}

// Sub-routine to get jwt user id
sub jwt_user_sub {
    // Prevent tampering attacks on the mechanism
    if (req.restarts == 0
        && (req.http.accept ~ "application/vnd.user-sub"
            || req.http.x-user
        )
    ) {
        return (synth(400));
    }

    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        // Backup accept header, if set
        if (req.http.accept) {
            set req.http.x-fos-original-accept = req.http.accept;
        }
        set req.http.accept = "application/vnd.user-sub";

        // Backup original URL
        set req.http.x-fos-original-url = req.url;
        set req.http.x-fos-original-method = req.method;
        set req.url = "/_jwt_user_sub";
        set req.method = "GET";

        return (hash);
    }

    // Rebuild the original request which now has the hash.
    if (req.restarts > 0
        && req.http.accept == "application/vnd.user-sub"
    ) {
        set req.url = req.http.x-fos-original-url;
        set req.method = req.http.x-fos-original-method;
        unset req.http.x-fos-original-url;
        if (req.http.x-fos-original-accept) {
            set req.http.accept = req.http.x-fos-original-accept;
            unset req.http.x-fos-original-accept;
        } else {
            // If accept header was not set in original request, remove the header here.
            unset req.http.accept;
        }

        if (req.http.x-fos-original-method == "POST") {
            return (pass);
        }

        return (hash);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    if (bereq.http.x-fos-original-method == "POST") {
        set bereq.method = "POST";
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    // On receiving the hash response, copy the hash header to the original
    // request and restart.
    if (req.restarts == 0
        && resp.http.content-type ~ "application/vnd.user-sub"
    ) {
        set req.http.x-user = resp.http.x-user;

        return (restart);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [built-in VCL](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#uncacheable-request-methods) says that only `GET` and `HEAD` requests are cacheable by default. You can override this and cache `POST` calls, but unless you perform explicit caching of the request body (which is stored in `req.body`), the body itself will only be processed once.

Because you perform `restart` calls in your VCL, the request body is processed multiple times. Unfortunately, at the 2nd attempt it is no longer available.

To tackle this issue, you can use the `std.std.cache_req_body(BYTES size)` function to explicitly cache the request body. Most of the times this will be for `POST` calls but the HTTP spec also allows you to have request bodies for `GET` calls.

See https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vmod_generated.html#func-cache-req-body for more information.

Here's how to implement this function in your `vcl_recv` subroutine:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = app;
     
    // Cache the request body for POST calls
    if(req.method == "POST") {
        std.cache_req_body(10K);
    }    
 
    // Retrieve user id and add it to the forwarded request.
    call jwt_user_sub;

    // Don't cache requests other than GET and HEAD.
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (hash);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding `std.cache_req_body(10K);` solved my issue.